# Meteor 1.3 modules - how to use npm imported libraries in the console?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I'm using Meteor 1.3 with ES32015 modules and native npm support, and I'm using momentjs from npm:

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

It all works fine in the project, but when I want to test out `moment` in the console, it says that it's `undefined`. Can I somehow import in the runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var moment = require('moment')()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `import moment from 'moment';`

Make sure you are putting () to the imported module.

`console.log(moment());`